# "The specified network location cannot be used" error when trying to back up windows virtualbox to shared folder location

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, backup, windows-registry

My main OS is Ubuntu and I am using windows 10 in Virtualbox. I am trying to create a backup image of my windows 10 Virtualbox Machine so I will be able to install that backup to my other physical laptop. When I tried to back up to my virtualbox shared folder(\VBOXSVR\Downloads) I get the following error:

[image]

I tried the following, no one does work.

***1.*** I open up services.msc and switch to the Automatic the followings. But it didn't work.:

- Block Level Backup Engine Service
- Remote Procedure Call (RPC) Locator
- RPC Endpoint Mapper
- Windows Backup

***2.*** I ran the Check Disk to fix disk errors.

***3.*** Checked that decimal symbol is set to .(dot)

***4.*** Added registry key to the Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\SystemCertificates

Registry Key Name:CopyFileBufferedSynchronously

Value:1

Answer (score 1):

Try mapping a network drive instead of using UNC. In a cmd prompt type

`net use x: \\vboxsvr\downloads`, then point the backup to x:

Comment: Thanks.`net use x: \\vboxsvr\downloads` command is successfully executed but backup windows doesn't allow to use x: for backup.https://imgur.com/a/aUMzVdw

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but I had the same issue going through the control panel. I got it to work when I found the cli to create a system image. Also, it doesn't accept mapped drives, had to use UNC path.

> 1. Start cmd/powershell as administrator
> 2. Enter: `wbadmin start backup -backuptarget:\\127.0.0.1\myshare -include:c: -allcritical -quiet`

The page I found the information:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/creating-a-system-image-for-back-up-by-using-the/04246478-b885-48dd-bc81-40190e6c5236

Also

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/wbadmin-start-backup